# Angularjs- use url in angular variable as embedded youtube src

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

I have the following code in my frontend of an angular app

```
  <iframe ng-hide="entry.videoLocation == null" width="560" height="315"
     ng-src="{{entry.videoLocation}}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
     allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <li>VL: {{entry.videoLocation}}
```

Basically, in some cases, entry.videoLocation contains the embed url of a youtube video. I would like to embed this video in my page if it's set, and not embed the video if it's null.

when the variable is set, the `iframe` tag shows up in my page and the url is printed in the `li` tag as expected, and both of these are missing when it's null.

However, the `src` attribute of the iframe tag is always missing. I have tried calling the attribute both `src` and `ng-src` to no avail.

Anyone know why it's not rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will helpfulto you,also not only for video but this will helps to you for PDF also,

```
<iframe class="img-responsive" src="{{pdfLoc| trustThisUrl }}" ng-style="{
                height: iframeHeight * 0.75 + 'px'
            }" style="width:100%"></iframe>
```

here trustThisUrl is just filter,

```
angular.module("deck").filter('trustThisUrl', ["$sce", function ($sce) {
        return function (val) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: you can change value of pdfLoc to video link

Comment: what's trustThisUrl?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
<iframe ng-hide="entry.videoLocation == null" width="560" height="315"
     ng-src="entry.videoLocation" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
     allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <li>VL: {{entry.videoLocation}}
```